# Set outgoing interface on Fortigate explicit proxy

Tags: firewall, proxy, fortigate, fortinet

I am testing the explicit proxy on a Fortigate 200D firmware 5.4 
WAN1 and WAN2 are both members of the wan load balancer interface. 
I need to set the proxy to use WAN1 but it it is defaulting to WAN2.

I've tried adjusting the explicit proxy rules and changing the outgoing interface. WAN2 works perfectly, but when I set my policy to WAN1 I am receiving "The page you requested has been blocked by a firewall policy restriction."

The *only* thing I can think of is on the wan load balancer wan2 was set as the first in sequence. I already changed that without any impact. Nothing is apparent in the logs and recent support received has been less than stellar.